# How to make a cross domain request and send cookies with the request

Tags: spring, angular, http, cookies, tomcat8

I'm developing 2 applications for backend and frontend (spring mvc and angular4), i host the spring app on tomcat server using the http port (8080) and my frontend using the http port (4200) , the communication between both of the apps is made using json.
To identify the user i'm using a session cookie.

The problem is that i came to a cross domain issue because i use different ports for both of the apps, the cookie is not send when i make a http post request.

**the only solution i found until now :**
When i put the angular app inside the /src/main/webapp of my spring project, following [this documentation](http://csetutorials.com/deploy-angular-2-maven-webapp-on-tomcat.html) , i dont have the issue and the cookie are automatically set but it's painful to do the previous steps everytime when i want to test something.

I thought also about some workaround like jsonp during the development process but i don't think this would be productive plus later on i need to execute some e2e testing.

Did anyone have an idea/example about how to make this cross domain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some researches i came out with this solution :
in term of security and scalability of my backend service the best way is to use CROS, any other solutions like JSONP, Proxy is just a workaround and this will bring nothing because of the **same-origin-policy** followed by browsers

Following [this documentation](https://www.moxio.com/blog/12/how-to-make-a-cross-domain-request-in-javascript-using-cors) the scenario that will happens :
1) the browser will send an OPTIONAL request 
2) the server will response with the allowed origin
3) if the our domain(the frontend domain/ angular app in my case) is verified the cookies will be automatically send in another request

the implementation that i made :
in the spring app :

```
//Some logic before this
if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type");

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        return ;
    }
// some logic after this
```

in the front app we can send the request using xhr like it's described in the attached link.

Answer (score 0):

Communication can be established via proxy.

Add in package.json `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json"` in `"scripts"`.

In `proxy.config.json` add:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://server.com:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you better explain how this code will solve my issue